# Does GeoLiteCityv6.dat has city and region data in it?

Tags: c, ipv6, geoip, maxmind

We are using GeoLiteCityv6 for detecting ipv6 address in our product.
However, we found that the state/region/city data can't be obtained from the database, while country data is available.

E.g. when resolving the IP address 2a02:2b88:2:1::419a:1 we get Country=Czech Republic, but Region is empty, also city is empty. We checked several IP addresses for and did not get any region/city information.

We are using C API for developing and the API we used are listed below:

```
GeoIPRecord *gir = GeoIP_record_by_addr_v6(gi, ip);
char *state = (char *)GeoIP_region_name_by_code(gir->country_code, gir->region);
printf("DB: state is %s.\n", state);         //return NULL
printf("DB: continent_code is %s.\n", gir->continent_code);  //right
printf("DB: country name is %s.\n", gir->country_name);  //right
printf("DB: country code is %s.\n", gir->country_code);  //right
printf("DB: region is %s.\n", gir->region);  //return NULL
printf("DB: city is %s.\n", gir->city);     //return NULL
```

So my question is, does the GeoLiteCityv6.dat NOT have relevant data for region/city, or we misuse the wrong API?

Many thanks here!

Answer (score 0):

no, it doesn't have city level info despite it's name. just download the same file in csv format and open it. no city level info.